# Expected Value addition/multiplication

Tags: probability

If I have two dice, and the numbers facing up after they are rolled are $W$ and $Z$, how can I compute $E((W+WZ))$?

I was thinking it is $E(Z)$ and $E(W) = 1 \text{ roll}\cdot \frac16 = \frac16$. Then looking at it as $E(W) + E(W)\cdot E(Z)$, so $\frac16+\frac16\cdot \frac16 = \frac7{36}$, but I'm not sure why that would necessarily be the case.

Comment: 6 states for W and 6 states for W, hence 36 cases with 36 probabilities. $$E{W + WZ} = sum_{i=1}^{36} \left(\ W + WZ right) P_r \left( W + WZ \right)$$

Comment: Any thoughts or guesses about the question?

Comment: For any two random variables $X,Y$, the expected value satisfies $E(X+Y) = E(X) + E(Y)$. For independent random variables $X,Y$, we also have $E(XY) = E(X)E(Y)$.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh I was thinking it is E(Z) and E(W) = 1 roll * 1/6 = 1/6.  Then looking at it as E(W) + E(W)*E(Z), so 1/6+1/6*1/6 = 7/36, but I'm not sure why that would necessarily be the case.

Comment: You're confusing probability and expectation.

Comment: I included your thought to your post. including your thought/ attempt in your post usually gain positive response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing expectation with probability. One die roll can result in a $1,2,3,4,5,$ or $6$, each with probability $\frac{1}{6}$. The expected value in the discrete case, is defined as

$$E(X)=\sum_{\text{all } x}xp(x)=(1\cdot \frac{1}{6})+(2\cdot \frac{1}{6})+(3\cdot \frac{1}{6})+(4\cdot \frac{1}{6})+(5\cdot \frac{1}{6})+(6\cdot \frac{1}{6})=3.5$$

Linearity of expectation gives

$$\begin{align*}
E(W+WZ)
&= E(W)+E(WZ) \\\\
&= E(W)+E(W)\cdot E(Z) \text{ (by independence})\\\\
&=3.5+{3.5^2}\\\\
&= 15.75
\end{align*}$$

Comment: How do you consider those are independent?

Comment: Because they are $2$ independent dice rolls, no?

Comment: I don't know, I could't take it for granted. :D